# What is the purpose of Target in Get-ItemProperty of powershell

Tags: powershell, file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcwWe.png)

I am wondering what's the purpose of Target? If the type of Target is hash, how to set the key/value.

```
PS Set-ItemProperty -Path a.txt -Name Target -Value { "key1":"value1"}
At line:1 char:58
+ Set-ItemProperty -Path a.txt -Name Target -Value { "key1":"value1"}
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token ':"value1"' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Comment: I think you mean set-content.

Answer (score 0):

As for your post title:

> What is the purpose of Target in Get-ItemProperty of powershell

Use [Get-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-7.3) to find out.

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'D:\temp\ZenMusic.mp3' | 
Get-Member) -match 'Target' | 
Format-List

# Results
<#
TypeName   : System.IO.FileInfo
Name       : Target
MemberType : CodeProperty
Definition : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] 
             Target{get=GetTarget;}
#>
```

As you can see, there is no setter for this property.

Comment: There is a codeproperty Target for symlinks, but setting it with set-itemproperty returns "Set accessor for property "Target" is unavailable."

Answer (score 0):

There is a target property for symlinks that's just a string, but it can't be set with set-itemproperty (Set accessor is unavailable).

```
New-Item -Path c -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value c:\  # elevated prompt


get-item c | % target | % gettype

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object


get-itemproperty -path c -name target

target       : {C:\}
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\admin\foo\c
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\admin\foo
PSChildName  : c
PSDrive      : C
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem


Set-ItemProperty -Path c -Name Target -Value c:\users

Set-ItemProperty : Set accessor for property "Target" is unavailable.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-ItemProperty -Path c -Name Target -Value c:\users
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-ItemProperty], SetValueException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetWithoutSetterFromCodeProperty,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemPropertyCommand
```